# Mac OS X 10.10.5 - How can I get remote access with Apple Screen Sharing with an activated Apple FileVault

Tags: macos, filevault, encryption

I'm a developer and work from home. At home I use an Apple MacBook Pro. At work I have a Mac mini with OS X 10.10.5 and FileVault enabled. This machine is on and booted to the login screen. Other people at work shouldn't have access to my user folder on the Mac Mini. I need to access the Mac mini from remote via Apple Screen Sharing though FileVault is enabled. How can I get this to work.

Comment: Please describe in simple words what you really need and what your current network setup/environment is. Something like: I am a salesman and traveling around. I use a MacBook Pro while traveling. At work I have a OS X Server machine. The server is off/on/booted to the login screen. Other people at work shouldn't have access to my user folder. I need to access the server via Apple Screen Sharing etc.

Comment: Hi klanomath,  I have my question rewrite to your suggestion. I hope that explains better for what I searching for. Greetings Sven

Comment: Why does it matter that FileVault is enabled?

Comment: The mac mini is in a datacenter and I wan't it secured for external access from that datacenter.

Comment: What I'm trying to clarify is this: Is FileVault somehow an obstacle in this scenario? I thought FileVault was just a file system encryption implementation method. How does it interfere with Apple Screen Sharing (/VNC/RDP/whatever)? Cheers.